# filter by nunique of one column while applying with exceptional conditions

Tags: pandas, transform

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name3', 'name2', 'name4', 'name4'],
                        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'],
                       ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
                       [np.nan, np.nan, 'Jan', np.nan, np.nan, 'Jan', 'Jan'],
                       [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])),
                columns=['sample ID', 'reference', 'country', 'month', 'value'])
df
```

I want to do filtering like:

```
df = df[df.groupby(['sample ID'])['reference'].transform('nunique') > 1] 
df
```

It gives:

[image]

However, in the `reference`column , I want treat `a` as more than 1 (namely, for any  `sample ID` , if  `reference` unique list  contains `a` for it , nunique being >1 even there is  `a` only.):

[image]

I can slice those with `a`, then concat processed dataframe together, but any better and easier way given my dataset is big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then add another condition to keep the "a" rows and combine it with OR (`|`):

```
out = df[(df.groupby(['sample ID'])['reference'].transform('nunique') > 1)
         | df['reference'].eq('a')]
```

Output:

```
  sample ID reference country month  value
0     name1         a     USA   NaN      1
1     name2         b     USA   NaN      2
2     name2         c     USA   Jan      3
4     name2         c     USA   NaN      5
```

Conditions:

```
  sample ID reference country month  value  nunique>1  eq('a')     OR
0     name1         a     USA   NaN      1      False     True   True
1     name2         b     USA   NaN      2       True    False   True
2     name2         c     USA   Jan      3       True    False   True
3     name3         b     USA   NaN      4      False    False  False
4     name2         c     USA   NaN      5       True    False   True
5     name4         b     USA   Jan      6      False    False  False
6     name4         b     USA   Jan      7      False    False  False
```